Multiple Consumer Clients vs. Single Consumer Client with Partition Clients for Azure Event Hub Event Fetching in Go
I'm building a Go app to fetch events concurrently from Azure Event Hub with 20 partitions. Each partition will have an ingress of about 0.8mb/sec which is near the limits of Azure's event hub so i want to read events from those partitions in a timely manner.
I followed this example, and according to docs i would assume that i need 1 consumerClient and then use this client to create 20 Partitionclients and fetch events respectively.
Although I soon noticed that when the partition clients share the same consumerClient i cannot achieve the maximum throughput of 2mb/s egress per partition from Azure Event Hub. I can only achieve up to 0.5-0.7mb/s per partition.
When i create 1 ConsumerClient for each PartitionClient my demo app can easily process 2mb/s per partition.
Why does creating multiple consumer clients result in faster event fetching compared to using a single consumer client?
I understand that this might me due to a single underlying connection to the Event Hub service, and the client might internally throttle requests based on internal connection limits but i would guess that the SDK would be smart enough to handle this case.
Should i just go ahead and use 1 Consumer Client for each partition? Are there any limits on active consumer clients per event hub?
Example code snippet
func main() {
    startTime := time.Now()
    consumerClient, _ := azeventhubs.NewConsumerClientFromConnectionString("blah")
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            totalBytes := 0
            partitionClient, _ := consumerClient.NewPartitionClient(strconv.Itoa(i), &azeventhubs.PartitionClientOptions{})
            defer partitionClient.Close(context.Background())
            for {
                events, _ := partitionClient.ReceiveEvents(context.Background(), 10, nil)
                if len(events) == 0 {
                    mbPerSec := float64(totalBytes) / time.Since(startTime).Seconds() / 1024 / 1024
                    fmt.Printf("Partition %d mb/s: %f\n", i, mbPerSec)
                    break
                }
                for _, event := range events {
                    totalBytes += len(event.Body)
                }
            }
        }(i)
    }
}


Can you share your code in the question?

I updated the question. All i do is to fetch all events from all partitions until there are no more events to fetch and report the processed mb/s. If i move the consumer client initialization inside each goroutine the mb/s increase from 0.7mbs/s to 2.4mb/s

A ConsumerClient owns the underlying AMQP connection and any partition clients spawned from it will share that connection.  By creating multiple consumer clients, you're opening multiple connections back to the service.
Performance will vary depending on a number of factors such as the processing performed, structure and size of data, batch size and prefetch count, host network environment, and other activities being performed by the application/host.  We would advise testing various configurations and tuning for your specific application.

Thanks for the answer but if you check the code snippet i do no processing at all. I just aggregate the consumed mb, and there are no other processes running in the host. I am wondering if Azure not only limits the per partition read to 2mb/s but also applies a 2mb/s read per consumer connection

You do no local processing, this is true - but network performance will vary depending on a number of factors, regardless.   The important part was that the difference is "I'm using one connection for all partitions" versus "I'm using one connection per partition" which does play into the throttling done by the service and TU usage.    Generally speaking, most applications find the sweet spot with some connection sharing rather than a 1:1, but at very high throughput 1:1 may be the better choice for your scenario.   Testing and tuning would help find the right ratio.
